# jump out of parenthesis, bracket, brace, quotes etc

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

Looking for simple and straightforward solution.
I'd like to jump out of parenthesis, bracket, brace, quotes etc while typing in "insert" mode. Obviously following mapping settings in ~/.vimrc work only for angle bracket in the last line:

```
inoremap <C-j> <Esc>f)a
inoremap <C-j> <Esc>f]a
inoremap <C-j> <Esc>f}a
inoremap <C-j> <Esc>f"a
inoremap <C-j> <Esc>f'a
inoremap <C-j> <Esc>f>a
```

This mapping using regexp doesn't work either. I wonder why:

```
inoremap <C-j> <Esc>f[)}"'\]>]a
```

This one works, but gives me too many highlights on every match:

```
inoremap <C-j> <Esc>/[)}"'\]>]<CR>a
```

I've see there are people invent a function for this purpose, but I like a single line solution more, if possible.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that uses `searchpair()` as provided by user Mass is great in finding the next closing `)`,`]`,`}`, or `>`. However, as `searchpair()` requires the opening and closing characters to be distinct, it cannot be used to find a closing `'` or `"` (eg. `searchpair('"', '', '"', 'W')` will not work).

From the comments, the OP wishes to use `search()` instead, in order to search for `'` and `"` as well. This can be achieved with

```
inoremap <C-j> <C-\><C-n>:call search('[>)\]}"'']', 'W')<CR>a
```

Note that in the regex `'[>)\]}"'']'`,

- the `]` needs to be escaped,
- the double quote should *not* be escaped, since it is within single quotes, and thus is treated literally,
- a literal single quote is given by two single quotes (ie. `''`).

One can refer to `:h expr-'` for details (and possibly contrast this with `:h expr-"`)

Comment: Thanks. It helps a lot. Indeed this one works. A bit tricky though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `searchpair` which goes to the end of the outer matching pattern.  In this case, we can use it to match `[({`.  It's also better than `f` or `/` since it is actually the enclosing pair, not just whatever happens to be next.

With knowledge of this function, it just remains to call it from insert mode:

```
inoremap <silent> <c-j> <c-\><c-n>:call searchpair('[([{]', '', '[)\]}]', 'W')<cr>a
```

A bit of a lengthy one-liner but it is something that could by typed fully on the cmdline, if one wanted.

I chose to use `<c-\><c-n>` to drop into normal mode followed by `a`.  This will ensure the cursor is placed after the closing `)` and not moved if there is no `)`.  Normally, one would try to use `<c-\><c-o>` to avoid true normal mode, but this would necessitate an additional cursor movement, which in turn could not be canceled if the `searchpair` fails.  Fortunately, situations where this difference would matter are rare.

Comment: Function searchpair() looks good. I still wanna add " and ' to the list. Enlightened by the idea of using built-in function, I tried search() function, `inoremap <C-j> <C-\><C-n>:call search('[>)\]}\"\']', 'W')<CR>a`. It doesn't work. It would work if I get rid of `\"\'` from the pattern. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @D.W The double quote should not be escaped, since it is within `'...'`. To "escape" the single quote, use `''`. From `:h expr-'`: `This string is taken as it is.  No backslashes are removed or have a special
meaning.  The only exception is that **two quotes stand for one quote**.
`

Answer (score 0):

This mapping gives me not perfect but ok result.

```
inoremap <C-j> <Esc>/[)}"'\]>]<CR>:<C-u>nohlsearch<CR>a
```

A good thing about it is it can jump to next `)}]"'` if i keep pressing `C-j`.